# Fade whole screen when FAB Menu is expanded

Tags: android, screen, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button menu which expands menu items when tapped. How do I achieve the same behaviour as displayed on the photo below? Please help.
[image]

I current ly have the following layout syntax:

```
<RelativeLayout
.
. 
/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/detailsDimView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
         android:visibility="gone" />

     <!--main content-->
     <LinearLayout
     .
     .
     />
     <FloatingActionsMenu
     .
     .>
            <!--Floating actions buttons-->
     </FloatingActionsMenu

</RelativeLayout>
```

but the main content does not fade. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: change the order, first main content then shadowView

Comment: Yeah it worked for me, but hopefully that'd include the action bar. I dont want to change my action bar code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<!-- Main Content here -- >


<!-- View to show the alpha background -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadowView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/floating_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">

    <!-- Floatingbuttons -->

   </FloatingActionsMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity you have a listener for expand and close the floating menu. There you should set the visibility of the shadowView.

Pseudocode Listener

```
 @Override
public void onMenuExpanded() {
    mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onMenuCollapsed() {
    mShadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

If you want to set the shadowView above the actionbar/toolbar

Try this

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary" />


<!-- Main Content here -- >

<!-- View to show the alpha background -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadowView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/floating_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
    fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">

    <!-- Floatingbuttons -->

   </FloatingActionsMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how about the action bar?

Comment: in my case i use the toolbar , so you can add the toolbar to your layout, so add the toolbar above the shadowView

Comment: all code work perfectly but for more visible background use this color code:#CCFFFFFF